# Dealing with touchMove events in iOS and Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, touch, dom-events

I'm adding iOS support to an Ember application which uses Flame.js. Most Flame.js widgets [don't have built-in support for touch events at the moment](https://github.com/flamejs/flame.js/issues/76), so I'm working on adding it to the ones I need. I've got `touchStart` and `touchEnd` working just fine for clicking and certain state transitions.

However, `touchMove` has been a mess so far. I need it for dragging, and to do that I need to track where the movement began and where it is. So far I haven't been able to get all that information consistently from `touchMove`. [Various](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) [resources](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/12/07/touching-and-gesturing-on-iphone-android-and-more/) suggest that I should be looking in the `event.touches` array for my data, but the jsFiddles I've built so far all throw `TypeError` when I try to get `length` on that array, which they claim is undefined. (The usual places to look, `event.pageX`, `event.pageY`, etc. are also undefined.)

I'm testing with an iPad and with [Phantom Limb](http://www.vodori.com/blog/phantom-limb.html), and with the latter I was able to get at data by accessing `originalEvent`, but that doesn't work on the actual iPad, I think because the `originalEvent` attribute is an artifact of how Phantom Limb works. (My theory is that accessing `originalEvent` is accessing the original `mouseMove` that Phantom Limb transformed into a `touchMove`.)

Why is the `event.touches` array undefined for me? More to the point, where can I get touch position data so I can drag?

Here's my [most representative jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/Awyg8/). Click the button to get a Panel, which you whould be able reposition by dragging its title bar if this was working. The extensions of Flame.State in the `titleView` of App.TestPanel are overriding the original states from Flame itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is just an artifact of PhantomLimb. We have a similar challenge, and use the following:

```
normalizeTouchEvent = function(event) {
    if (!event.touches) {
        event.touches = event.originalEvent.touches;
    }
    if (!event.pageX) {
        event.pageX = event.originalEvent.pageX;
    }
    if (!event.pageY) {
        event.pageY = event.originalEvent.pageY;
    }
};
```

Comment: It took a little tinkering (I wound up having to normalize more than just `touches`, `pageX` and `pageY`) but it works better now. Sweet!

Comment: @pjmorse i'd love to hear what else you needed to normalize and how you did it. gist?

Comment: `screen[X|Y]` and `client[X|Y]` for starters. I still have some glitches - maybe tonight.

Comment: Nice, props for sharing and giving back to Flame.js.